# Qt HTML5 App Plugin System

Tags: ruby, html, qt

I am going to be developing a HTML5 Application using the Qt Framework.  It will be a fairly large application and will need some sort of plugin system. I want to use Ruby for scripting these plugins or extensions.

How would I be able to achieve this, that is, how can I use Ruby to script my plugins?

Comment: Thats a pretty broad question, don't you think? What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: something like "you need this and this to get it work" or "HTML5 is awesome and has this cool thing where you can do this and this"... you know, stuff like that